# Helping with healthcare, python code to count how many daycares in AR have what capacity based on quality

Tags: python

I'm semi-new to python and I'm helping someone count a .csv file with two columns separated by a comma.
On the left it has numbers 0,1,2,3 with regards to quality of the facility. On the right it has the capacity of said place. There are about 1.5k facilities. 
I need to find the sum of each 1, 2 or 3 quality facility capacity and ignore the 0's.
Thank you for your help. Here is my broken code that I gave up on after a while.

```
import numpy as np
c0=0
c1=0
c2=0
c3=0
zeros = ()
count = 0
fp = open ("D:/ASU SCHOOL STUFFS/IFT333/Labs/Lab1/V2ez.csv", "r")
for line in fp:
    count += line.rstrip().split(",").count("0")
    print (count)
    zeros = (line.split(","))

for line in fp:
    items = line.rstrip().split(",")
    if items[0] == "0":
        c0 += items[1]
    elif items[0] == "1":
        c1 += items[1]
    elif items[0] == "2":
        c2 += items[0]
    elif items[0] == "3":
        c3 += items[0]

print(c0)
print(c1)
print(c2)
print(c3)

fp.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reading `csv` you don't need `numpy` really. Just use the inbuilt `csv` module.

A simple example for your problem

```
import csv

with open("D:/ASU SCHOOL STUFFS/IFT333/Labs/Lab1/V2ez.csv") as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile)

    capacities = dict()
    for row in data:
        rating = int(row[0])        
        capacity = int(row[1])

        # Ignore all ratings of zero.
        if rating==0:
            continue

        # Increment the value for this rating. If no entry exists for this rating, then 
        # add one.
        try:
            capacities[rating]+= capacity
        except KeyError:
            capacities[rating] = capacity

    for k,v in capacities.items():
        print(f"Facility rating {k} has a capacity of {v}")
```

The concept is to use a dictionary, where the keys correspond to the ratings, and the value is the capacity for that rating. For each row, we find the rating in the dictionary and increment the capacity by the required amount.

This assumes the capacities are all integers. I'm sure you could figure out a small change if that is not the case.

You could also do this more elegantly with `defaultdict` but hopefully this example is relatively simple and understandable. Hope this helps.

Comment: This was a great help. It was really neat to see a different way to do something. I've been finding that there are a million ways to solve the same problem when programming.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Good luck with your project